# Equal implies Less-Than-Or-Equal in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm trying to prove the simplest thing ever in Coq:

```
Require Import Coq.Structures.OrdersFacts.
Require Import Coq.Structures.Orders.
Lemma easy: forall a b : nat, (a = b) -> (a <= b).
Proof.
  intros.
  apply le_lteq.          (* doesn't work *)
  apply LeIsLtEq.le_lteq. (* doesn't work *)
```

But I get the following error:

```
The reference le_lteq
was not found in the current
environment.
```

This is a bit strange because I *do* see it in [Coq.Structures.Orders](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Structures.Orders.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in the link you provided, the definition of `le_lteq` is not at top-level, but hidden behind other modules. The general solution when faced with this problem is to use `Locate`.

```
Locate le_lteq.
```

will tell you which definitions (in scope, that is available after `Require`) have that name and how to call them.

Note that it also works with notations.

```
Locate "=".
```

---

In this particular case, it will not work indeed because `le_lteq` is not only hidden behind modules, but behind functors.
For instance it appears in

```
Module OT_to_Full (O:OrderedType') <: OrderedTypeFull.
 Include O.
 Definition le x y := x<y \/ x==y.
 Lemma le_lteq : forall x y, le x y <-> x<y \/ x==y.
End OT_to_Full.
```

Meaning you would have to instantiate `OT_to_Full` with a module of type `OrderedType'`.

If there is no particular reason to use `Coq.Structures.Orders` then I would rather look for a lemma on natural numbers directly.

```
Search "=" "<=".
```

does not yield what you want. Instead we will use `subst b` to replace `b` with `a` in the goal.
And this is fine because we have a proof of `a <= a` which we find using

```
Search (?x <= ?x).
```

which prints

```
le_n: forall n : nat, n <= n
```

The proof is then:

```
Lemma easy :
  forall (a b : nat),
    a = b ->
    a <= b.
Proof.
  intros a b e.
  subst b.
  apply le_n.
Qed.
```

Comment: I get back `No object of basename le_lteq`

Comment: You are correct, I answered a bit too fast. I now completed my answer.